# Feature Request: use `<br># ... # <br>` for large text inside of a Table

Tags: feature-request, markdown

### A Feature Request Regarding Markdown Tables

I was hoping to find a way to insert text of the same size as headers inside of markdown language tables.

```
| Fruits        |    Description                |
|---------------|-------------------------------|
| kiwi          |  <br># Large Text Here #<br>  |
| sangria melon |  <br># Large Text Here #<br>  |
```

```
| Fruits        |    Description                |
|---------------|-------------------------------|
| kiwi          |  <br># Large Text Here #<br>  |
| sangria melon |  <br># Large Text Here #<br>  |
```

My feature request is that when we do the following...

> 1. Wrap text in `#`
> 2. Wrap the `#` in forced line-breaks by using the `<br>` tag.

The text `<br># ... #<br>` inside of the table would render as if it was a Markdown language header. The text would be a large font size in bold.